# How do I programatically determine which Shopify plan (Basic, Shopify, Advanced) a store is on?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I'd like for my app pricing to be based on the merchant's Shopify plan. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a nice way to map either [ShopPlan.displayName](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2021-10/objects/ShopPlan#fields-ShopPlan-OBJECT) or [Shop.plan_name](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/shop#resource_object) to one of the three non Shopify Plus plans (Basic, Shopify, Advanced - I can use `ShopPlan.shopifyPlus` to determine if the merchant is using a Shopify Plus plan.).

Is there a programmatic way to determine what plan a merchant is on?

It seems that this has been asked in the past with no official response from Shopify on the matter:

- https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/enumeration-of-plan-name-from-get-admin-shop-json/td-p/273614

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you care? To what benefit would that be, assuming Shopify exposed that?

Comment: @DavidLazar "I'd like for my app pricing to be based on the merchant's Shopify plan.". The merchant's Shopify plan is a decent proxy for both usage and ability to pay. I listen to lots of webhooks, so knowing what the merchant's plan is gives me a rough idea of how much activity I'll have to accommodate from a load perspective. I'd prefer this over something like usage charges.

Comment: You can do better than that. The plan a shop is on is poor metric to choose to base your App pricing on. Instead, isolate what actually taxes your App in terms of use, and then turn that into appropriate pricing. You'll get a lot farther with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make api call for shop.json and can check this "plan_name" value within it to get the plan name for the merchant store
[image]

Comment: This doesn't help. There are lots of possible values that plan_name can have that doesn't determinatively map to one of the 4 plans that Shopify offers. You take a look at the forum link I posted in the original post for more context.

Comment: Here in this you will get the actual running plan o the store, even if it is not from the given 4

Comment: That information isn't useful. Some shops return values like: "npo_lite", "grandfather", "npo_full", "custom", etc.